# Insertar en una tabla dependiendo del resultado de otras

Tags: postgresql

Tengo 3 tablas; **tabla1**, **tabla2**, **tabla3**. En la tabla1 tengo una columna llamada *cantidad_uso* con un valor de 18. Y mediante de un trigger agregar cantidades en la tabla2 hasta llegar a 18, al llegar a esa cantidad necesito insertar datos en la tabla3.
Pero al llegar 18 en la tabla2 no me inserta en la tabla3, solo cuando inserto otra cantidad mas en la tabla2, ahí rencién me inserta en la tabla3.

el comentario de arriba es un ejemplo del inconveniente que tengo.

```
create trigger ajustar_insumos_utilizados after
insert
    on
    public.insumos_utilizados_det for each row execute function trg_insumos_utilizados();
```

Funcion:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION public.trg_insumos_utilizados()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
declare 
            retorno record;
            ultcod integer;
            cant_ya_utilizada integer ;
            cant_a_ser_usada integer ;
            tipo_uni_med integer;   
        
BEGIN
    if TG_OP = 'INSERT' then -- select * from insumos_utilizados_det
        for retorno in select * from insumos_utilizados_det where insu_uti_nro = (select max(insu_uti_nro) from insumos_utilizados_cab) loop
            
            cant_ya_utilizada = (select coalesce(stock_uso, 0) from stock where depo_nro = retorno.depo_nro and items_nro = retorno.items_nro);
            cant_a_ser_usada = (select cant_uso from items where items_nro = retorno.items_nro);
            tipo_uni_med = (select uni_med_nro from items where items_nro = retorno.items_nro);
        
            -- select * from stock
            -- select * from items
        
            /* falata ver la parte de descontar stock cuanto es por litros*/
            if tipo_uni_med  = 2 then -- litros
                
                if cant_a_ser_usada = cant_ya_utilizada then /*Se ejecuta cuando la cantidad llega a 18*/
                
                    ultcod = (select coalesce(max(ajuste_cod), 0) + 1 from ajuste_cab);
                    insert into ajuste_cab -- select * from ajuste_cab ac 
                    values(
                        ultcod,
                        current_timestamp,
                        'PROCESADO',
                        (select funcio_nro from insumos_utilizados_cab order by insu_uti_nro desc limit 1),
                        (select sucu_nro from insumos_utilizados_cab order by insu_uti_nro desc limit 1),
                        'AJUSTE POR INSUMO UTILIZADO'
                    );
                    
                    insert into ajuste_det -- select * from ajuste_det 
                    values(
                        ultcod,
                        retorno.depo_nro,
                        retorno.items_nro,
                        1, --ajuste por insumo utilizado
                        retorno.insu_uti_cant,
                        (select items_precio from items where items_nro = retorno.items_nro) 
                        
                    );
                
                    -- actualizamos el nuevo valor disponible en stock
                    perform * from sp_stock2(retorno.depo_nro, retorno.items_nro);
                
                else /*se ejecuta cuando aun no llega a 18*/
                
                                    -- actualizamos el nuevo valor de cant_utilizado en stock
                    perform * from sp_stock1(retorno.depo_nro, retorno.items_nro, retorno.insu_uti_cant);
            
                
            end if;
            
        end if;
            
        end loop;
    end if;
    
    return null ;

    -- select * from insumos_utilizados_cab iuc 
    -- select * from insumos_utilizados_det 
END
$BODY$;
```